# Flask Module Not Found in UWSGI

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, uwsgi

I am running a docker container to host a flask application the docker file is as below

```
FROM python:3.7.7-alpine3.11

ENV FLASK_APP api.app:app

RUN apk add --no-cache mariadb-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev 
RUN apk add --no-cache uwsgi-python3 uwsgi-http bash
RUN adduser -D api
USER api

SHELL [ "/bin/bash", "-c" ]

WORKDIR /home/api

COPY . .
RUN python -m venv venv
RUN venv/bin/pip install -r requirements/requirements.txt
RUN venv/bin/pip install .


# run-time configuration
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT [ "./boot.sh" ]
```

the code for boot.sh is as below

```
exec uwsgi --plugins http,python3 --http :5000 -b 32768 --http-keepalive --thunder-lock --manage-script-name --mount /=myapp.app:app --lazy-apps --die-on-term -H venv
```

The container gives error while running.

I enter the container (run some other command in boot.sh to keep the container up)
`docker exec -it <containerid> sh`
try to run the above command it gives me the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./query_api/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, jsonify
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='/') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
```

I have seen multiple stackoverflow queries and found that we have to set the proper path of virtual env i did that too but got the same error

```
exec uwsgi --plugins http,python3 --http :5000 -b 32768 --http-keepalive --thunder-lock --manage-script-name --mount /=myapp.app:app --lazy-apps --die-on-term -H /home/api/venv
```

I read somewhere that we have to provide the PYTHONPATH.

`export PYTHONPATH=/home/api/venv/`
and then when i execute the uwsgi command i get the below error

```
Python version: 3.8.2 (default, Feb 29 2020, 17:03:31)  [GCC 9.2.0]
!!! Python Home is not a directory: root/test !!!
Set PythonHome to root/test
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = 'home/venv'
  PYTHONPATH = '/home/venv'
  program name = 'home/venv/bin/python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/home/api/home/venv/bin/python'
  sys.base_prefix = 'home/venv'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'home/venv'
  sys.executable = '/home/api/home/venv/bin/python'
  sys.prefix = 'home/venv'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'home/venv'
  sys.path = [
    'home/venv/lib/python38.zip',
    'home/venv/lib/python3.8',
    'home/venv/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f8034d60d48 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

I am not sure from where its picking python 3.8. I checked the python version using python -V and got it as

```
~ $ python -V
Python 3.7.7
~ $
```

The app.py contains a simple hello world program.
I am struggling from last 2 days to debug the same as i am new to flask and uwsgi. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `virtualenv` inside Docker? That seems like an anti-pattern to me. You use `virtualenv` to isolate your dependencies from other apps or the system itself, which is the same thing you achieve using Docker. Perhaps if you simplify your Dockerfile, you might solve your issues.

Comment: Hi Stefan,Thanks. But I am trying to replicate one of the project that my colleague had and for him the set up (older alpine version) is working fine. However I will try without the virtual env and let you know. However as per my understanding the same issue can also occur in the local machines virtual env.

Comment: I agree, same issues can occur during local development. Usually, the development process when using Docker (and I'll use python as an example) is to develop app locally using `virtualenv`, ensuring that everything is working fine. After that, containerize the app using the same commands used during local development, but in this case without `virutalenv` because it's just overhead. In the end, when you are sure everything works as well with containers, you optimize image.

Comment: I tried on my local linux system without docker and i still get the same issue

Comment: Well, that would be a flask/python question. :)

Comment: in local you are using docker or normal project files ? and can you give any example how you are mounting virtualenv in local and how you are running the uwsgi in local ?